# In the code, the type of the lambda is mismatched, how does it work?

Tags: android, kotlin, epoxy

I'm using the `Epoxy library` on `Android`.

What I'm curious about is why the `parameter` of the `lambda expression` doesn't get an error when the type doesn't match.

The `listener` is a `lambda expression` that takes an `Int type` as a parameter.

But `listener(addDetailClicked)` works normally.

Shouldn't it be `listener(Int)`? or `listener({ i -> addDetailClicked(i) })`.

Actually, I don't know why it works even after I write the code.

How is this possible?

**Model**

```
@EpoxyModelClass(layout = R.layout.item_routine)
abstract class EpoxyRoutineModel() : EpoxyModelWithHolder<EpoxyRoutineModel.Holder>() {
    @EpoxyAttribute
    var workout: String = "see"

    @EpoxyAttribute
    var curPos: Int = 0

    @EpoxyAttribute
    lateinit var listener: (Int) -> Unit // this

    override fun bind(holder: Holder) {
        holder.workout.text = workout
        holder.add_btn.setOnClickListener {
            listener(curPos)
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class RoutineItemController(
    private val addDetailClicked: (Int) -> Unit)
    : EpoxyController() {
    private var routineItem : List<RoutineItem>? = emptyList()

    override fun buildModels() {
        var i:Int =0
        routineItem?.forEach {
            when(it) {
               is RoutineItem.RoutineModel ->
                   EpoxyRoutineModel_()
                       .id(i++)
                       .curPos(i++)
                       .workout("d")
                       .listener(addDetailClicked) // why? listener(Int) or listener({ i -> addDetailClicked(i) })
                       .addTo(this)
           }

        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class WriteRoutineFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding : FragmentWriteRoutineBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var epoxyController : RoutineItemController
    private val vm : WriteRoutineViewModel by viewModels { WriteRoutineViewModelFactory() }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentWriteRoutineBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        epoxyController = RoutineItemController(::addDetail)
        binding.rv.adapter = epoxyController.adapter
        binding.rv.itemAnimator = null

        return binding.root

    }
    private fun addDetail(pos: Int) {
        vm.addDetail2(pos)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you missed the fact that `EpoxyRoutineModel_` contains setters for data types found in `EpoxyRoutineModel`. For example, `EpoxyRoutineModel.curPos` is of type `Int`, so `EpoxyRoutineModel_.curPos()` is a function declared as:

```kotlin
fun curPos(Int): EpoxyRoutineModel_
```

(or similar)

Similarly, `EpoxyRoutineModel.listener` is of type `(Int) -> Unit`, so `EpoxyRoutineModel_.listener()` is declared as:

```kotlin
fun listener((Int) -> Unit): EpoxyRoutineModel_
```

So `listener()` is a function that receives another function (which itself receives `Int`). So we can provide `addDetailClicked` there.

Comment: then you're saying that it's the same thing as `Java's user.setcurPos()`, `user.setName()`, `user.setNumber()`, etc...?

Comment: I don't have the code of `EpoxyRoutineModel_`, but it seems so. For example, `curPos(i++)` clearly shows that `curPos()` is a function receiving `Int`, so it looks like some kind of a setter.

Comment: So, the reason `listener(addDetailClicked)` is possible is that `listener()` is not a function call that takes an `Int` as a `parameter`, but simply calls the `settter function` of the `listener` to initialize the `listener property`? So, is it possible to pass `addDetailClicked` of `(Int) -> Unit` appropriate to the type of `listener property` as an `argument`?

Comment: It seems so, yes. If `curPos()` is a setter for `Int`, then similarly, `location()` should be a setter for `(Int) -> Unit` function. Which actually makes sense, because you use `EpoxyRoutineModel_` to build `EpoxyRoutineModel`. The latter contains the property for `(Int) -> Unit` function, so the builder have to provide a way to set it.

Comment: You should be able to ctrl+click on `.listener(addDetailClicked)`. I guess you will see a function declared something like this: `fun listener((Int) -> Unit): EpoxyRoutineModel_`. This will confirm that this function actually receives another function.

Comment: It's a little different, but it's true. Actually
`public EpoxyRoutineModel_ listener(Function1<? super Integer, Unit> listener) {
    onMutation();
    super.listener = listener;
    return this;
  }`

Here `super.listener = listener` seems to mean it.
And curPos also `public EpoxyRoutineModel_ curPos(int curPos) {
super.setCurPos(curPos);
    return this;
  }` As you said, these functions exist. After all, it was a `setter`!